# Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741511

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, windows-server-2008, vbc

I have a dedicated server: Windows Server 2008 RS2 with IIS7.0

Last friday one of the sites crashed with that error, but no significant change was made either on the server or on the site. And today, another site crashed with the same error:

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741511.

This message appears anytime you browse the site, it doesn't matter the directory or file you ask for.

And also, it started gradually:

1. The site dent-talks.com went down.
2. The folders located on a private directory (stated on a web.config file) fell down, any time you tryed to browse on the client's area on odontologos.com.co, that error came up.
3. Now both of the sites are down, in all their roots.

This is the complete error statement (www.odontologos.com.co or www.dent-talks.com):

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\9c51023f\d360f8bb_5e87d001\CKEditor.NET.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\d8e05ce8\9f7d87bc_5e87d001\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\650eef3a\9bdb18c0_5e87d001\neodynamic.webcontrols.imagedraw.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\1138dc57\8f0344c1_5e87d001\Recaptcha.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\e330c9dc\36e18bc2_5e87d001\Solmetra.Spaw2.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\App_WebReferences.bst-jbyz.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\2830c7f6\e41fe6bd_5e87d001\Imazen.Crop.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\807e254e\c01820bd_5e87d001\ImageResizer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\6126b1b4\e2c4d2c0_5e87d001\obout_Show_Net.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\5e6dc224\b8478dc1_5e87d001\SanitizerProviders.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\4e1beb73\5e5cdfc2_5e87d001\Solmetra.Spaw2.SpawFM.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\a86440f8\58c0cfbe_5e87d001\LightBox.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\0a0624ba\24d48fc3_5e87d001\System.Web.Ajax.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\assembly\dl3\2871e30c\fda1f5c1_5e87d001\skmControls2.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\App_Web_publica1.master.cdcab7d2.tbvu2a2y.dll" /D:DEBUG=1 /debug+ /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\" /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Collections.Specialized,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,System.Configuration,System.Linq,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.DynamicData,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Xml.Linq /warnaserror- /optionInfer+  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\App_Web_publica1.master.cdcab7d2.tbvu2a2y.0.vb" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\App_Web_publica1.master.cdcab7d2.tbvu2a2y.1.vb" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fffd5ea\8ea6c084\App_Web_publica1.master.cdcab7d2.tbvu2a2y.2.vb"

Please help!!!

I've tryed changing the account of the Application Pool in IIS, restarting the server, recycling all the applications and nothing works!

What I'm trying to achieve: to overpass and solve this error so that the sites come up live again.

Thanks thanks thanks!!!

Comment: Update: the server OS is Windows 2012 r2 + Plesk

Comment: I solved it!!! It appears that a windows update was causing the error. I deleted the updates and it solved it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C0000139 (-1073741511) exception code means "Entry point not found". It could be missing dll, you can use depends.exe to investigate the dll dependencies.